# download files from heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a utility on ruby on rails that uploads files to public folder. And by providing the link to that file i can download that file.

It is working fine on local rails server.

I deployed my work to heroku. where uploading part works. but when i click to login button it simply gives error

```
The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
```

on looking to heroku logs, i noticed it is a routing error.

Any one please let me know what i am missing. as i am really beginner with heroku.

Thanks regards,

**Update**
Here are the heroku logs

```
2014-08-12T12:44:02.705737+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered internships/show.html.erb within layouts/application (23.2ms)
2014-08-12T12:44:14.260997+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/resume/Saghir%20Resume1.docx" host=shielded-atoll-2450.herokuapp.com request_id=87d911ee-2bb3-40e7-923b-a8029f7ab6ff fwd="39.44.84.14" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=27ms status=404 bytes=1182
2014-08-12T12:44:14.253695+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/resume/Saghir%20Resume1.docx" for 39.44.84.14 at 2014-08-12 12:44:14 +0000
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256004+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-12T12:44:14.253706+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/resume/Saghir%20Resume1.docx" for 39.44.84.14 at 2014-08-12 12:44:14 +0000
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256011+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256016+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256007+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/resume/Saghir%20Resume1.docx"):
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256009+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256014+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256017+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256012+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256056+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256059+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256054+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256022+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256063+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256019+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256020+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256064+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256060+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256078+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256066+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256057+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256094+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256023+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256077+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256072+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/resume/Saghir%20Resume1.docx"):
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256074+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256090+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256080+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256098+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256091+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256025+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256104+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256027+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256097+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256085+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256095+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256102+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-08-12T12:44:14.256083+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
```

Comment: bunch of issues might be the reason. If you would post the logs it could be helpful

Comment: Epehemeral file system, read-only file system, multiple slugs...the list goes on.

Comment: @andreydeineko i have posted logs. plz check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link is to `/resume/Saghir%20Resume1.docx` (`/resume/Saghir Resume1.docx`) but you say its in the public folder -- is the upload directory `/public/resume/file_name`? And are you set for Rails to `serve_static_assets`?

As `@CodeGnome` pointed out, Heroku is an ephemeral filesystem so the entire approach is a bad idea -- typically you'd use Amazon S3 or a similar filestore for your uploaded files. Even if your routes are right, the file you uploaded can be on a different dyno because you're running more than one or because you've redeployed.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku has something called the Ephemeral filesystem, so during the dyno’s lifetime its running processes can make use of it, but any file stored here will be discarded after the dyno has finished, so yes it does save the file, but after that it is deleted so it won't find it.

A very common approach is using paperclip and Amazon S3 for handling/storing the uploads, and those are pretty straightforward to install too. Here is a great article explaining how to do so: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3